# How to show a specific city using mapbox in iOS?

Tags: ios, mapbox

I'm trying to stylize a specific polygon (a city) so that the only the city boundary would be visible. How can I achieve that using mapbox?

Comment: have you tried anything? if yes than share your code here so that we can help you with that.

Comment: Well, I'm actually new to mapbox, so trying to understand their mapping concepts. I've found a way (https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/styling-polygons/) to mark polygons based on a selector like country, but I want to select a specific country / city. I don't even know how to find the polylines that mark a specific city. If I could find that then I'll probably try to add a layer with the polyline information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the built-in data sources in TileMill:

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/add-geodata/

Or a data source you've obtained elsewhere and can reference on your filesystem:

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/add-shapefile/

Then you style it:

https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/crashcourse/styling/

Comment: Does MapBox have a geodata set of city boundaries? I googled and checked mapbox documentation but failed to locate anything similar.